# NextSeo is not overriden in each component when I use DefaultSeo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, meta-tags

I want to change the Head tag dynamically using next-seo.

Browser validation will reflect NEXTSeo for individual pages, but Twitter, Firebase's card validation tool, etc. will respond to the default next-seo-config.js.

Does anyone know what to do?

Similar problems:

- [Facebook debugger does not pick up Next.js next-seo meta tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66717038/facebook-debugger-does-not-pick-up-next-js-next-seo-meta-tags)
- https://github.com/garmeeh/next-seo/issues/113
- https://github.com/garmeeh/next-seo/issues/99

_app.js

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Script from 'next/script'
import Head from 'next/head'
import * as gtag from '../lib/gtag.js'
import { GA_TRACKING_ID } from '../lib/gtag'
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import redux, { persistor } from '../components/store/redux.js'
import { DefaultSeo } from 'next-seo'
import SEO from '../../next-seo.config'
import Header from '../components/block/Header'
import Footer from '../components/block/Footer'

import { config } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css'
config.autoAddCss = false

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
    const router = useRouter()
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleRouteChange = (url) => {
            gtag.pageview(url)
        }
        router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange)
        return () => {
            router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange)
        }
    }, [router.events])

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />
            </Head>
            {/* Analytics */}
            <Script
                async
                src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${GA_TRACKING_ID}`}
            />
            <Script
                id="analytics"
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: `
                    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
                    gtag('js', new Date());
                    gtag('config', '${GA_TRACKING_ID}', {
                    page_path: window.location.pathname,
                    });
                `,
                }}
            />
            <DefaultSeo {...SEO} />
            <Provider store={redux}>
                <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
                    <Header />
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                    <Footer />
                </PersistGate>
            </Provider>
        </>
    )
}
```

_document.js

```js
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';

class MyDocument extends Document {
    static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
        const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
        return { ...initialProps };
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <Html lang="ja">
            <Head>
                <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
                <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
            </Head>
            <body>
                <Main />
                <NextScript />
            </body>
        </Html>
        );
    }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

Page.js

```js
import { NextSeo } from 'next-seo'

const Page = () => {
    const title = "title"
    const description = "description"
    const url = "https://test.com/"

    return (
        <div>
            <NextSeo
                title={title}
                description={description}
                url={url}
                canonical={url}
                openGraph={{
                    ur: url,
                    title: title,
                    description: description,
                    type: "article"
                }}
            />

            <div>contents</div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Page
```

Answer (score 0):

Self resolved.
The cause of not being reflected was redux-persist.

Reference ↓
https://qiita.com/miyabiya/items/14e4f133d5df5d53cd77

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.